Flask KeyError when accessing app config set in a different function
Question Description
I am encountering an issue in a Flask application where configurations set in one function of the startup script throw a KeyError when accessed in another function. Although I have ensured the use of the application context and everything seems to be set up correctly, the problem persists.
Detailed Explanation
I have a Flask application where the configuration is set in the init_app_config function and then attempted to be accessed in the init_aps_task function. Here is a simplified version of the relevant code:

Code to initialize configuration:

def init_app_config():
    from app.admin.models import DBSystemConfig, DBUser
    with app.app_context():
        config_obj = DBSystemConfig.query.filter_by(dictkey="log_storage_space_full").first()
        assert config_obj is not None, "Missing system configuration: log storage space full handling"
        config_dict = json.loads(config_obj.value)
        config_dict.update({"is_full": False, "now_transfer_pdf": False})
        app.config["log_storage_space_full"] = config_dict


Code to access the configuration in APScheduler tasks:

def init_aps_task():
    from app.aps_task import storage_space_check, expired_logs_clean
    storage_space_check()
    expired_logs_clean()
    ApsConfig.scheduler.start()


Code accessing the configuration in the storage_space_check function:

from flask import current_app

def storage_space_check():
    with app.app_context():
        is_full = current_app.config["log_storage_space_full"]["is_full"]


When storage_space_check executes, I encounter the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/app/aps_task.py", line 70, in storage_space_check
    current_app.config["log_storage_space_full"]["is_full"] = False
KeyError: 'log_storage_space_full'

Additional Information
It's worth noting that if I directly execute the configuration logic from init_app_config in the global scope of the script, instead of calling it from within a function, I do not encounter this KeyError. This suggests that the issue might be related to how the function's execution context is managed or how the application context is preserved when the function is called.
Question
How can I ensure that storage_space_check can correctly access the configuration set in init_app_config? Is there a possibility that the context or configuration has been corrupted in some way?

I ensured that init_app_config is called before any related function calls and that configurations are set within an application context.
I wrapped the related function calls within with app.app_context(): to ensure the presence of the context.
I checked the log outputs to confirm that the configurations were indeed set after init_app_config was executed.


I think APScheduler job is running from another process which doesn't have access to the same memory space the flask app is running. So it can't access the config because it's not there. The best way in my opinion to deal with this is to use a separate in memory caching like redis and r/w from there. Then all processes should have access to the same data.
